# Align loop output in one row

Tags: html, css, row

*I have this code in which the image output* `$check` *or* `$uncheck` *and title* `$val_c` *are inside a loop, what i want is to output everything in one row using* `<div class="col-sm-12">` *but what i always get is a column. what i want is like this*

image_title_______________image_title________________image_title

*what im getting is like this...*

image

title

image

title

image

title

*heres is the code*

```
<div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            ';

                            $funcs->viewSurvey();

                            $array4 = $funcs->viewSurvey();
                            $searchengine = $array4['searchengine'];
                            $sum = $array4['sum'];

                            $searches = explode(',', $searchengine);
                            $searchesa = array("google","yahoo","bing");

                            $check = '<img src="images/checked.png" height="40px" width="40px">';
                            $uncheck = '<img src="images/unchecked.png" height="40px" width="40px">';

                            foreach ($searchesa as $key_a => $val_c) {

                                $found = false;

                                foreach ($searches as $key_b => $val_d) {
                                    if ($val_c == $val_d) {
                                        echo ''.$check.'<h3 class="head8">'. $val_c.'</h3>' ;     
                                        $found = true;
                                    }     
                                }
                                if (!$found)
                                    echo ''.$uncheck.'<h3 class="head8">'. $val_c.'</h3>' ;

                            }

                            echo '
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: yes.. thankyou for the effort, i already solved it. i just placed the  `<div class="col-sm-12">` inside the first foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style

```
h3 {
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: i would like to use only the grid system... i just don't know where to place it

Comment: thankyou for the effort, i already solved it. i just placed the  `<div class="col-sm-12">` inside the first foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. i just placed the  `<div class="col-sm-12">` inside the first foreach.